# JUnit tests pass only when I run them one by one. Probably incorrect threading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, junit

UPD: Marked answer solved the problem see it's comments for small fixes.

First of all forgive me for butchered code. This problem drives me crazy, I tried a lot of stuff in order to determine the source of the problem, but failed.

I have a Spring Boot web app, which has the FMonitor service. It works while the app is running and notifies me, when a file with ".done" extension appears in certain folder. When I run the app it works flawlessly (at least it seems like that).

I decided to practice with tests and threw three simple ones. They work with success when I run them one at a time. However, when I run the whole class of tests, only first one passes, other two fail.

My tests check the System.out and compare it with desired output. And here is the strangest thing to me. Thats what happens.

First test passes, output of the FMonitor is exactly like in assertEquals.
*Found test1*
*Found test2*
*Found test3*

Second test fails. Output is oddly doubled for some reason:
*Found test1*
*Found test1*
*Found test3*
*Found test3*

And then third one fails. Output is triple now:
*Found test*
*Found test*
*Found test*

My guess is that I do something entirely wrong with threads, so fm.monitor() somehow catches all of events and something like that. I'm very confused. I tried a lot of things with how to implement threading here, I'm not good with it, but it still works same. Also I thought that @Async annotation for monitor() could mess up something, but removing it didn't change anything. Help, please.

**BunchOfTests**

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FMonitor.class)
public class BunchOfTests {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private Executor executor;

    @Autowired
    FMonitor fm;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Runnable task = () -> {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
            fm.monitor();
            System.setOut(System.out);
        };
        executor = (runnable) -> new Thread(runnable).start();
        executor.executeTask(task);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        File file1 = new File("C:\\dir\\test1.done");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\dir\\test2.done");
        File file3 = new File("C:\\dir\\test3.done");
        file1.createNewFile();
        file2.createNewFile();
        file3.createNewFile();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        file1.delete();
        file2.delete();
        file3.delete();
        Assert.assertEquals("Found test1\r\n" + "Found test2\r\n" + "Found test3\r\n", outContent);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Runnable task = () -> {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
            fm.monitor();
            System.setOut(System.out);
        };
        executor = (runnable) -> new Thread(runnable).start();
        executor.executeTask(task);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        File file1 = new File("C:\\dir\\test1.done");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\dir\\test2.txt");
        File file3 = new File("C:\\dir\\test3.done");
        file1.createNewFile();
        file2.createNewFile();
        file3.createNewFile();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        file1.delete();
        file2.delete();
        file3.delete();
        Assert.assertEquals("Found test1\r\n" + "Found test3\r\n", outContent);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Runnable task = () -> {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
            fm.monitor();
            System.setOut(System.out);
        };
        executor = (runnable) -> new Thread(runnable).start();
        executor.executeTask(task);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        File file = new File("C:\\dir\\test.done");
        file.createNewFile();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        file.delete();
        Assert.assertEquals("Found test\r\n", outContent);
    }
}
```

**FMonitor**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.srpingframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

@Service
public class FMonitor {

    @Async("fMonitor")
    public void monitor() {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\dir");
        try {
            WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService();
            path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
            WatchKey key;
            while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                    String filename = event.context().toString();
                    if (filename.endsWith(".done")) {
                        processFile(filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
                    }
                }
                key.reset();
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processFile(String filename) {
        System.out.println("Found " + filename);
    }
}
```

**AConfiguration**

```
import org.srpingframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.srpingframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.srpingframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "fMonitor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() { return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); }
}
```

Comment: Use a proper executor and after the test shut it down so that threads get stopped.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried that, didn't help

Comment: You tried what? I also don't really understand your test. Why are you executing a task in an executor while Spring Boot already executes that task in a thread.... Each time you call `monitor` it will launch a new one. Adding one to the list of tasks because there is just 1 application. So you end up with multiple tasks, 1 for each test. SO the first executes 1 task, the second 2 tasks and the third 3 tasks. NOr do you need the `Executor` in your test.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried using "proper executor with shutdown". ExecutorService. If you know how to do it properly, feel free to share.

Comment: As stated the issue is you are calling a method on a spring managed bean. Each time you call `monitor` it will schedule a new task. Each test adds one. You don't need the executor. I would argue that your `FMonitor` is slightly wrong. You should store the `WatchService` as an instance variable and add a method annotated with `@PreDestroy`. After the test, call this method to cleanup the watcher.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, so, I end up with three monitors running. But how to make it launch only once then and without Executor? I can't just `fm.monitor()` in the beginning of the test. It will stuck in its loop without progressing through the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you should cleanly stop the `WatchService` when you are done. Implement a method that does this and annotate with `@PreDestroy`.

```
@Service
public class FMonitor {

    private final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault.newWatchService();


    @Async("fMonitor")
    public void monitor() {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\dir");
        try {
            path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
            WatchKey key;
            while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                    String filename = event.context().toString();
                    if (filename.endsWith(".done")) {
                        processFile(filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
                    }
                }
                key.reset();
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processFile(String filename) {
        System.out.println("Found " + filename);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
      try {
        watchService.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Next don't use `@SpringBootTest` it doesn't add anything but complexity and slowness to your test. Instead, just instantiate it yourself and use a proper executor to launch the `monitor` method.

```
public class BunchOfTests {

    @Rule
    public OutputCaptureRule output = new OutputCaptureRule();
    
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private final FMonitor fm = new FMonitor();

    @After
    public void cleanUp() throws Exception {
      fm.shutdown();
      executor.shutdown();
      while (!executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS));
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        executor.submit(() -> fm.monitor());

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        File file1 = new File("C:\\dir\\test1.done");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\dir\\test2.done");
        File file3 = new File("C:\\dir\\test3.done");
        file1.createNewFile();
        file2.createNewFile();
        file3.createNewFile();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        file1.delete();
        file2.delete();
        file3.delete();
        Assert.assertEquals("Found test1\r\n" + "Found test2\r\n" + "Found test3\r\n", output.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        executor.submit(() -> fm.monitor());

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        File file1 = new File("C:\\dir\\test1.done");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\dir\\test2.txt");
        File file3 = new File("C:\\dir\\test3.done");
        file1.createNewFile();
        file2.createNewFile();
        file3.createNewFile();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        file1.delete();
        file2.delete();
        file3.delete();
        Assert.assertEquals("Found test1\r\n" + "Found test3\r\n", output.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        executor.submit(() -> fm.monitor());

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        File file = new File("C:\\dir\\test.done");
        file.createNewFile();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        file.delete();
        Assert.assertEquals("Found test\r\n", output.toString());
    }
}
```

Something like this should more or less do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. There is a typo tho, you forgot a "do { /code/ }" for do while construction in @After of Test class. Also for assertEquals I changed simple "output" for "output.toString()". In case someone will try to run your example

Comment: Ther is no missing do. It is just an empty while loop which will wait upon termination of the executor.